# C++ Curl can't connect using LetsEncrypt pem files using SSL_CTX_FUNCTION

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, https, lets-encrypt

I have a server which has an SSL certificate installed from LetsEncrypt. I have the following files, which are currently marked as `live`:

- cert.pem
- privkey.pem
- fullchain.pem
- chain.pem

The part of my code where I specify the certificate is:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, *sslctx);
```

And the `sslctx-function` I use:

```
static CURLcode sslctx(CURL *curl, void *sslctx, void *parm) {
    X509_STORE *store;
    X509 *cert = NULL;
    BIO *bio;
    const char *mypem = // ANY PEM FILE CONTENTS HERE? 
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        "XXXXXX WHICH PEM FILE? XXXX\n"
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(mypem, -1);
    PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, &cert, 0, NULL);
    if (cert == NULL) {
        cout << "Failed reading SSL-certificate" << endl;
        Exit(false);
        }
    store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store((SSL_CTX *)sslctx);
    if (X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert) == 0) {
        cout << "Error adding SSL-certificate" << endl;
        Exit(false);
        }
    X509_free(cert);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return CURLE_OK;
    }
```

However, when I try to connect to my server over https, curl returns me the error: `Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

I can't figure out which LetsEncrypt generated `PEM`-file I require to make sure I can verify the peer...

If I disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, the request succeeds but is insecure which is unacceptable for the application

**Some extra info** 
The content from `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` are:

```
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-$
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined
#LogLevel warn
#ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Always ensure Cookies have "Secure" set (JAH 2012/1)
#Header edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*)(;\s*secure)??((\s*;)?(.*)) "$1; Secure$3$4"
```

The content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{site}-le-ssl.conf` contains:

```
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{site}/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{site}/privkey.pem
```

Comment: I don't have the answer, but does it work using the utilities provided so that you have something to compare with?

Comment: What utilities are you referring to?

Comment: I have already tried using the Mozilla certs. Still the same error

Comment: I was thinking of the scripts doing the cert updates. I use letsencrypt myself, but I think I misunderstood where you had problems.

I've noticed that one needs to be very careful about which machine/owner you assign to your certs. A client may (should?) refuse a connection to "x.y.z" if the cert is for "y.z" or "x" etc. I've somehow messed up my own setup so that I need to add exceptions to my own email clients to accept the certs, both local and external.